# How to evaluate an xpath against an open shadow root?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

(simplified example) I am given a DOM tree (labelled `dom`) with an open shadow root, like this DOM tree:

```html
<div id="parent">
  #shadow-root (open)
    <div id="child1">a</div>
    <div id="child2">b</div>
</div>
```

and I am given an XPath (labelled `xpath`) to run inside the shadow root, for example: `//div[contains(@id, "child1")]`. I need to return the first `Node` inside the shadow root that matches the `XPath`. In this case, the `div#child1` would be matched.

So far it has not worked for me. Attempted:

1. `document.evaluate(xpath, dom, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE)` - returns null, because (I think) the element is inside the shadow root document-fragment, not the root document or the `dom`
2. `document.evaluate(xpath, dom.shadowRoot, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE)` - raises `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The node provided is '#document-fragment', which is not a valid context node type.` - which makes sense.
3. Using `const xe = new XPathEvaluator(); xe.evaluate(...` in the above two cases, with the same results.

Online, all the StackOverflow questions have suggested one of the following, which is not applicable in my use case:

1. in the context of Selenium/Cypress, use one of their built-in methods
2. switch from XPath to querySelector
3. move the children from the shadow root to inside the main host, and run the XPath there

Is there any other way to evaluate this XPath?

Comment: `//div[contains(@id, "child1")]` should return always something … is the html example really there if your code is running?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed: The key issue that the shadow DOM is isolated by design.

Comment: I don't have time right now to verify a complete solution, but try pushing on #2 by wrapping the shadow DOM markup in a single root element.  If that works, and the markup adjustment is acceptable for your use case, you're done; if not, when the node is `#document-fragment` and you want to use the built-in XPath 1.0 engine, you might have to write procedural JavaScript to iterate over the fragment's elements, evaluating the XPath on each individually.